# Copy Row into another Table with an Update

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Ok, the title may be difficult to understand, but this is what I want to do.

I have a Table 'A' with a few columns.
I have a Table 'B' with the exact same columns.

During my program flow, I insert a few rows from 'A' into 'B' (sort of a temp cache).
Column data in 'A' may change, but when someone clicks the 'restore' button, I wanna copy those rows from 'B' back into 'A' and overwrite those rows with the same id as the ones i want to copy from 'B'.

E.g.

```
Table A:

1  :      Hi |
2  :      Friends |
3  :      What's up
```

During the flow i backup id 1 and 2

```
Table B:

1  :      Hi |
2  :      Friends
```

Now I do some stuff and table A changes a bit

```
Table A (changed):

1 :       Hi diddely doo |
2 :       Amigo's |
3 :       What's up
```

Now I realise my changes are wrong, and I want to put the records with id 1 and 2 back in their original state, from table 'B'.

Is there a 'simple' sql to do that, without fetching those id's 1 by 1 and update it 1 by 1?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you also think of what would happen if your scripts died in the middle of those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JOIN in UPDATE statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE ta SET ta.text = tb.text
INNER JOIN tb ON ta.id = tb.id
```

Or with implicit join:

```
UPDATE ta, tb SET ta.text = tb.text
WHERE ta.id = tb.id
```

You can delete and reinsert, that way you don't have to specify columns if both tables have the same table scheme:

```
DELETE FROM ta WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tb)

INSERT INTO ta
SELECT * FROM tb
```

Comment: Well I know of that one, but when there are ALOT of columns you have quite the sql query... I was just wondering if there is a 'shortcut' if both tables have the exact same columns

Comment: Your question only has one column and you said you don't want to fetch "those id's 1 by 1 and update it 1 by 1", so I assumed you where selecting the ID's in table b and updating them seperately.

Comment: Well I just used 1 column as an example, in reality I want to do it with alot of columns.

Comment: Updated my answer, but you should update your question to reflect your intention.

Comment: dude, you're last edit hit the spot. Why didn't I think of that? Thanks